# Points to polygons transform, inserting columns

Tags: sql, pgadmin-3

In this task I'am transforming points to polygons. I have table `POINTStbl` with four columns: `ID`, `YEAR`, `CODE`, `POINT` and i need to create table `POLYGONStbl`, where will be three same columns(with same values): `ID`, `YEAR`, `CODE` and one new: `GEOMETRY`. 
   I stuck here - with this code I'am able to create `POLYGONStbl` with only one column `GEOMETRY`. Is there any option how can I copy others columns in this new column? Is this command `INSERT_INTO` able to insert others(`ID`,`YEAR`..) columns?
 
 
 `INSERT INTO polygonstbl (geometry) (
   SELECT ST_Buffer(point, 300, 'quad_segs=8') 
   FROM pointstbl
);`

POINTStbl

```
ID|   CODE |YEAR|POINT                   |
1 |1332A138|2010|01010000208A150000C3D3..|
2 |1234A010|2010|01010000208A1500003E7.. |
3 |1223A009|2010|01010000208A150000002.. |
4 |1221A237|2011|01010000208A150000ED9...|
```

POLYGONStbl - I'am able to create with that code

```
|GEOMETRY                |
|1616545645645641328456..|
|FDDSFD5SF4DS56F4DS56F.. |
|1FD351SD32F1DS32F1SD3.. |
|48DFD7SF89D7SF98DS8DF...|
```

POLYGONStbl - I need to create

```
ID|   CODE |YEAR|GEOMETRY                |
1 |1332A138|2010|1616545645645641328456..|
2 |1234A010|2010|FDDSFD5SF4DS56F4DS56F.. |
3 |1223A009|2010|1FD351SD32F1DS32F1SD3.. |
4 |1221A237|2011|48DFD7SF89D7SF98DS8DF...|
```

Comment: Aren't you just missing the ID, CODE, and YEAR columns in the SELECT and INSERT column lists?  Have you tried it?  What does the doc say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the other fields to your `INSERT` query :

```
   INSERT INTO polygonstbl (id, code, year, geometry) (
     SELECT id, code, year, ST_Buffer(point, 300, 'quad_segs=8') 
     FROM pointstbl
   );
```

Another way is to create directly your table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE polygonstbl AS (
  SELECT id, code, year, ST_Buffer(point, 300, 'quad_segs=8') AS geometry 
  FROM pointstbl  
);
```